# asp.net session expiry not redirecting page with forms authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

in my MVC 3 application on login it executes the following:

```
    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
```

My web.config has the following:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

After that I set a few session variables. Problem is that if I leave a page for long enough for the session to expire, then click on a page then instead of redirecting me to the login screen, it is raising an exception in the controller with the null reference of the session variable.

```
     public ActionResult Fixit(int Id, int cardId)
        {
            var model = new FixitVM();

            model.PointsMaxValue = (int)Session["MAXPoints"];
        }
```

Is this expected behavior? I would have thought the redirect to the login page would happen before this code fired.
Is there some configuration I can set to make the redirect happen before it tries to evaluate this code?

Comment: Authentication and session are managed by two different cookies.  What is the timeout on your session?  Is it less than 2880?  It's possible that the session cookie has expired while the authentication cookie is still good.

Comment: OK yes, that makes a lot of sense session timeout is probably 20 minutes (I think that is the default)

Comment: Sounds good. Let me know if that was the problem so we can get this marked as answered.

Comment: Yes, you can safely mark this one as answered - thanks very much. I've added some code to align the value of the two cookies when the Session starts

Comment: "we" can't mark this as answered. _you_ have to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication and session are managed by two different cookies.  It's possible that the session cookie has expired while the authentication cookie is still good.